# Invite friends dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, invite

I have an invite dialog on my page:

```
<a href="#" onclick="sendRequestToManyRecipients(); return false;" >xx</a>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     FB.init({appId  : 'myappid', status : true, cookie : true, oauth: true});
     function sendRequestToManyRecipients() {
         FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', message: 'xxx'},requestCallback);
      }
      function requestCallback(response) {
        // Handle callback here
      }
 </script>
```

When the invited user clicks the invite, he gets linked to the app, but I want the user to get redirected to a page like http://www.facebook.com/pages/xxx/xxx?sk=app_xxxx.

How can I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714670/facebook-redirect-app-from-canvas-page-to-fan-page - look at this

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible without some custom coding - the requests interface exists to drive traffic to apps on facebook, not to page tabs, there's no way to have Facebook send users to a tab when they accept the request.

You could just implement something on your canvas landing page that redirects users back to a page tab based on the information in the request as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

previous version of the `apprequest` which is `request-form` this was possible:   [How can I include a link in a FB app request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994833/how-can-i-include-a-link-in-a-fb-app-request/7045499#7045499)

However current version of `apprequest` : facebook guys lets only redirect to your app: `https://apps.facebook.com/yourapp`

@Vihay comments helps this custom workaround to redirect to page.

Hoping next version apprequests, facebook enables redirect to links within the fb app.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with previous answers. Facebook will redirect to your app, which is just a Facebook wrapper around a page you can provide. That page can then use a client-side redirect to whatever page you'd like (like what Klout does).